# Argparse, handle repeatable set of items

Tags: python, argparse

Is it possible to create a set of optional arguments that are related and repeatable?

Let's say I have three arguments -a, -b, -c that form a set, 
**-a is required, but -b and -c are optional. (Updated)**

I would like an ability to specify multiple set of these.

```
Script.py -a 1 -b 2 -c 3    -a 4 -c 6   -a 7 -b 8    -a 10
```

This will be parsed as a list of dict as follows

```
[
    {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3},
    {"a":4, "c":6},
    {"a":7, "b":8},
    {"a":10}
]
```

Comment: How are you going to specify set boundaries on the command line? using multiple spaces is a visual help, but when your shell parses the command for execution, multiple spaces are not going to help. So your Python app will just receive: `-a 1 -b 2 -c 3 -a 4 -c 6 -b 8 -a 10`. How do you define sets now? Is it a valid assumption that elements of each set are sorted, so you'd know you've reached another set because you had _c_ before, and now you've reached to _a_?

Comment: The spaces were just to distinctly show possible interaction. I agree there is no good way to break them into sets without a required argument, thanks for pointing this out, I should have mentioned that -a is a required argument, this lets us to identify set boundaries. I thought to simply use list for each argument and zip them as tuples, but that will be incorrect when some optional args are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to make arguments repeatable is to use an 'append' action type:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', action='append')
parser.add_argument('-b', action='append')
parser.add_argument('-c', action='append')
argv = '-a 1 -b 2 -c 3    -a 4 -c 6   -a 7 -b 8    -a 10'
args = parser.parse_args(argv.split())
print args
```

produces:

```
Namespace(a=['1', '4', '7', '10'], b=['2', '8'], c=['3', '6'])
```

Unfortunately it does lose some information.  There's no way to associate the '4' with the '6' instead of the '8'.

If you use '--' to separate blocks of arguments, then this iterative parser might do the job:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# SUPPRESS keeps the default None out of the namespace
parser.add_argument('-a', type=int, default=argparse.SUPPRESS, required=True)
parser.add_argument('-b', type=int, default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
parser.add_argument('-c', type=int, default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
argv = '-a 1 -b 2 -c 3  --  -a 4 -c 6 --  -a 7 -b 8  --  -a 10'

arglist = []
rest = argv.split()
while rest:
    args,rest = parser.parse_known_args(rest)
    rest = rest[1:]  # remove the 1st '--'
    print args
    arglist.append(vars(args))
print arglist
```

producing:

```
Namespace(a=1, b=2, c=3)
Namespace(a=4, c=6)
Namespace(a=7, b=8)
Namespace(a=10)

[{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}, 
 {'a': 4, 'c': 6}, 
 {'a': 7, 'b': 8}, 
 {'a': 10}]
```

I'm not sure if it is robust enough.  I made `-a` required, so omitting it from one of the groups will raise an error.

---

Or adapting farzad's iterator:

```
def by_sets(iterator, start):
    set = []
    for val in iterator:
        if set and val == start:
            yield set
            set = [val]
        else:
            set.append(val)
    yield set

argv = '-a 1 -b 2 -c 3  -a 4 -c 6 -a 7 -b 8  -a 10'
# print list(by_sets(argv.split(), '-a'))
# [['-a', '1', '-b', '2', '-c', '3'], ['-a', '4', '-c', '6'],... ['-a', '10']]

arglist = []
for aset in by_sets(argv.split(), '-a'):
    arglist.append(vars(parser.parse_args(aset)))
print arglist
```

produces:

```
[{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}, {'a': 4, 'c': 6}, {'a': 7, 'b': 8}, {'a': 10}]
```

The loop can also be written as a comprehension:

```
[vars(parser.parse_args(aset)) for aset in by_sets(argv.split(), '-a')]
```

Comment: Great, thanks, accepting hpaulj's solution as the question was argparse specific., though farzad provided helpful comments and code. Thank you both

Answer (score 1):

We could iterate over command line args and add them one by one to the set, if we reached to '-a' which marks the start of another set, we'll create a new set. This code sample does not check for invalid user input though.

```
import sys

def get_pairs(iterator, start):
    sets = []
    for val in iterator:
        if val == start:
            sets.append({})
        sets[-1][val] = next(iterator)
    return sets

print get_pairs(iter(sys.argv[1:]), '-a')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, [@hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) and [@farzad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9394/farzad) – I found your answers very helpful.  Another way to implement farzad's iterator:

```
more_itertools.split_before(arg_list, lambda arg: arg == '-a')
```