# Can argparse manage multiple sets of positional arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

I am wanting to handle input of multiple sets of data from the command line, and I'm not sure how to do it.  I am thinking that having multiple optional arguments with multiple positional arguments would work, but I don't know how to do it.

For example, I want to get data like:

```json
{
  'id': 23423423
  'host': 'hostname'
  'port': 234
}
```

I want to be able to enter multiple sets on the command line.  How might I do this?

My idea was to have a command line like:

`python check.py -d 23423423 hostname.com 234 -d 22332322 hostname2.com 234`

I have been looking at argparse to see about how this might be done, but how this might be done is eluding me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Argparse, handle repeatable set of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269760/argparse-handle-repeatable-set-of-items)

Comment: I would also suggest that if you need to pass in structured data, then passing in json - either as a file, or a command-line string - might be a better option.

Comment: I would describe that as multiple sets of `optionals`, flagged arguments.  With `append` and `nargs=3` you'll get a list of lists, which you can restructure after parsing.

Comment: @hpaulj That might be preferable to my answer, which tries to have `arparse` itself handle building the `dict`.

Comment: @match Unfortunately the point is to create a json file with the data.  If the json existed, this wouldn't be necessary.  I have people that are having difficulty structuring the data properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feels like it could be improved, but you can define a custom subclass of `_AppendAction` to take the 3 arguments and build a `dict` using them.

```
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()


class Config(argparse._AppendAction):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string):
        id_ = int(values[0])
        port = int(values[2])
        d = {"id": id_, "host": values[1], "port": port}
        return super().__call__(parser, namespace, d, option_string)

p.add_argument("-d", nargs=3, action=Config, metavar=("ID", "HOST", "PORT"))

print(p.parse_args())
```

Then

```
$ python3 tmp.py -d 23423423 hostname.com 234 -d 22332322 hostname2.com 234
Namespace(d=[{'id': '23423423', 'host': 'hostname.com', 'port': 234}, {'id': '22332322', 'host': 'hostname2.com', 'port': 234}])
```

---

(I would have preferred something like

```
def Config(t):
    return {"id": t[0], "host": t[1], "port": int(t[2])}

p.add_argument("-d", nargs=3, action='append', type=Config)
```

where the act of aggregating the 3 arguments into a single object
is separate from appending the resulting `dict` to the destination,
but each individual argument is passed to the type separately, rather than the trio of strings being passed as a single tuple. Alas.)

Comment: I like that this goes the extra mile and gives me the dict.  I wasn't necessarily asking for that.  This works great for me.  The only thing I am wondering is if the help text can be fixed so it would say -d id host port instead of -d d d d.

Comment: Yes, it can. I'll update.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done as follows.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')
parser.add_argument("-d", nargs="+", action='append')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.d)
```

Running `python check.py -d 23423423 hostname.com 234 -d 22332322 hostname2.com 234` will be parsed as a list of lists as below.

```
[['23423423', 'hostname.com', '234'], ['22332322', 'hostname2.com', '234']]
```